# How much soil needed for cactus maintenance?

Tags: plant-health, cactus, outdoor

I have several *Sabila* cactuses that look like the picture below.

I was considering filling up a [cut wine bottle like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIHaS.jpg) with soil and using it as a pot for the cactus.

Is this possible or do they need more soil?

They would be living outdoors so they would receive lots of sun since we’re in the Caribbean.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've still got the same problem mentioned here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47467/maintain-cactus-without-soil.

Comment: In that other question I wasn't going to use soil. Would they need more soil?

Comment: Yes, for large cactus like the one in your picture, but more importantly,, a drainage hole in the bottom of the glass or they'll rot

Answer (score 2):

The amount of soil has little influence ; Drainage holes and the nature of the soil are the important factors. Cacti generally need "fast" drainage soil , mostly sand ,gravel, or similar. I have a large "Christmas " cactus that gets covered with blooms. It grew well and was overflowing the pot. I got a larger pot ( with plenty of holes), added potting soil around the edges and planted the cactus without disturbing the root ball. Over several months it deteriorated. I pulled it out of the pot and realized I had made a big mistake to use potting soil because it holds too much moisture. I repotted in sand and gravel and it is now doing very well, although it is about half the size it was before I put it into potting soil.

Answer (score 1):

When determining the pot size of any plant, take note of it's size. A plant can reach further than the edges of a pot with it's leaves, but when it does, it's closer to being rootbound than having enough space, so when transplanting/repotting it's best to use pots where the plant's leaves will all fall within the perimeter of the pot's edges. Any less and it will soon enough start feeling cramped. The bottles are too small. Try Dame Jeanne bottles?